# SwiftUI: dismissing `ActionSheet` or `sheet` dismisses its parent view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view `FooView` in a navigation stack presented via a `NavigationLink`.

Now `FooView` has a button that will trigger a `ActionSheet`:

```
struct FooView: View {
    @State private var showActions = false

    var body: some View {

<snip>

            Button(action: {
                showActions = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
            }
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActions) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Actions"),
                            message: nil,
                            buttons: [
                                .default(Text("Option 1")) {
                                    // TODO
                                },
                                .default(Text("Option 2")) {
                                    // TODO
                                },
                                .cancel()
                            ])
            }
```

The problem is:  when the `ActionSheet` is dismissed (either cancelled or selected option), its parent view, i.e. `FooView` is also dismissed, i.e. pops up from the navigation stack.

Is there a way to prevent it doing that?

More importantly, why is this happening?  What triggers `FooView` going away?

iOS version: iOS 15 on iPhone

XCode: 14.2

EDIT:

Here is a minimum reproducible code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ViewDismissApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                TabView {
                    ContentView(title: "Tab 1")
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Tab1", systemImage: "wifi")
                        }
                    ContentView(title: "Tab 2")
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Tab2", systemImage: "wrench.adjustable")
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink {
                FooView()
            } label: {
                Text(title)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FooView: View {
    @State private var showActions = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Foo View")
            
            actionButton()
        }
    }
    
    private func actionButton() -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            showActions = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActions) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Actions"),
                        message: nil,
                        buttons: [
                            .default(Text("Option 1")) {
                                // TODO
                            },
                            .default(Text("Option 2")) {
                                // TODO
                            },
                            .cancel()
                        ])
        }
    }
}
```

When creating this sample project, it seems to me that having `TabView` inside `NavigationView` is related to this problem. But I still don't know why.

Comment: You haven't posted enough to reproduce the problem. Please include a [mre].

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've added a minimal reproducible example code.

Comment: "When creating this sample project, it seems to me that having TabView inside NavigationView is related to this problem" -- you have your answer there, too. `NavigationView` should be inside `TabView` and not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, since you wrapped TabView inside NavigationView, their items will share the same NavigationView. So, if you change the property `showActions`, as usual, the trigger to present sheet is activated, and the `FooView` itself is rendered again by calling the computed property `body`. And vice versa when it turns to `false`. At this time, the current flow is:

> showActions = false -> NavigationView -> TabView -> ContentView

Consequently, the NavigationView state will reset and go back to root in this case.

The right way to do it is as you said above `When creating this sample project, it seems to me that having TabView inside NavigationView is related to this problem.`

```
TabView {
    ContentView()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            //Content here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There was a reason that we used `NavigationView` outside the `TabView`, but I cannot recall it at this moment. And I don't understand this:  `Consequently, the NavigationView state will reset and go back to root in this case.`.  Why does it go back to root?   EDIT: i.e. why did not the change apply only locally to `FooView` ?

Comment: I remember the reason of using `NavigationView` outside the `TabView`:  so that the child views via `NavigationLink` do not show the tabs.  Here `FooView` will have tabs shown at the bottom if I move `NavigationView` inside `ContentView`.

Comment: @user1783732 `TabView` is not designed to be nested in a `NavigationView`. if you want to hide the tab bar, just do `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)`

Comment: @user1783732 It's kind of a graph under the hood, and SwiftUI will decide which view needs to render again. Your choice is whether you'll keep following the rule or not. As Sweeper commented, you need to choose another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks. However it seems that `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)` is only available in iOS 16 or newer. Is there another way I hide the tab bar in iOS 15?  (or do I have to use UIKit instead of SwiftUI?)